# RSpec different DateTime format in response than passed attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to test if response is serialized in a proper way (I'm using Fast JSON API serializer). To do so I've create a sample response which I want to compare:

```
let!(:journey_progress) { create(:journey_progress, started_at: current_date) }

let(:current_date) { 'Thu, 16 Jul 2020 17:08:02 +0200' }

let(:serializer_response) do
{
  'data' => [
    {
      'id' => 1,
      'type' => 'percent_progress',
      'attributes' => {
        'percent_progress' => 0.5,
        'started_at' => current_date,
      }
    }
  ],
}
end

it 'serializes journey with proper serializer' do
  call
  expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq(serializer_response)
end
```

In the response I'm getting:

```
-"data" => [{"attributes"=>{"percent_progress"=>0.5, "started_at"=>"Thu, 16 Jul 2020 17:08:02 +0200"}],
+"data" => [{"attributes"=>{"percent_progress"=>0.5, "started_at"=>"2020-07-16T15:08:02.000Z"}],
```

What is this `2020-07-16T15:08:02.000Z` format and why it's not in the same format which I passed to created `journey_progress` object ?

Comment: It's JSON time format - ISO 8601.

Comment: Use `'started_at' => Time.parse(current_date).utc.as_json`

Comment: Better to define `current_date` as `Time` object like `let(:current_date) { Time.parse('Thu, 16 Jul 2020 17:08:02 +0200') }` and then use `'started_at' => current_date.utc.as_json`

Comment: Yup, you were right, thanks a lot! please leave an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails uses [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) as [default format of JSON serialization for Time objects](https://apidock.com/rails/Time/to_json).

Also, it's better not to rely on ActiveRecord time parsing and use same Time object either for the expectation and for creating the record:

```rb
let(:current_date) { Time.parse('Thu, 16 Jul 2020 17:08:02 +0200') }

let(:serializer_response) do
{
  'data' => [
    {
      'id' => 1,
      'type' => 'percent_progress',
      'attributes' => {
        'percent_progress' => 0.5,
        'started_at' => current_date.utc.as_json,
      }
    }
  ],
}
```